# Special treatment of NAs when use dplyr case_when to create a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my sample data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA, 1, 1, 0, 0 , NA),
                x2 = c(1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0),
                x3 = c(0, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1),
                x4 = c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0))
```

I’d like to create a new column, `score`, based on below conditions

**For first `case_when` on `x1` and `x2`:**

- If there is 1 in either x1 or x2 -> add 1 to score
- If both x1 and x2 values are 0 -> add 0 to score
- None of above -> NA should be return returned

**For second `case_when` on `x3` and `x4`:**

- If there is one in either x3 or x4 -> add 1 to score
- If both x3 and x4 values are 0 -> add 0 to score
- None of above -> NA should be returned

The problem arises when I want to sum over those `case_when` functions. Any instance of `NA` resulted in score to be NA.

```
x %<>%
  mutate(
    score =
      case_when(x1 == 0 & x2 == 0 ~ 0L, x1 == 1 | x2 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ NA) +
      case_when(x3 == 0 & x4 == 0 ~ 0L, x3 == 1 | x4 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ NA)
  )
```

I tried `sum` function with `na.rm = T`, but it does not work either.

```
x %<>%
  mutate(
    score1 = sum(
      case_when(x1 == 0 & x2 == 0 ~ 0L, x1 == 1 | x2 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ NA) +
      case_when(x3 == 0 & x4 == 0 ~ 0L, x3 == 1 | x4 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ NA), 
      na.rm = T
    )
  )
```

The result that I want is like `score` column with values:  `1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1`

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The NA condition doesn't seem to be needed. You can simplify the statement like: `x %>% mutate(score = case_when(x1 == 1 | x2 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ 0) + case_when(x3 == 1 | x4 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

You can combine `rowwise()` with your 2nd attempt:

```r
x |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(
    score = sum(
      case_when(x1 == 0 & x2 == 0 ~ 0L, x1 == 1 | x2 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ NA),
      case_when(x3 == 0 & x4 == 0 ~ 0L, x3 == 1 | x4 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ NA), 
      na.rm = T
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      x1    x2    x3    x4 score
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1    NA     1     0    NA     1
#> 2     1    NA    NA     1     2
#> 3     1     0    NA     1     2
#> 4     0     0     1    NA     1
#> 5     0    NA     0     0     0
#> 6    NA     0     1     0     1
```

Or we can use `rowwise()` and `sum()` for a more concise solution.

```r
x |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(score_a = sum(x1, x2, na.rm = TRUE),
         score_b = sum(x3, x4, na.rm = TRUE),
         score = sum(score_a, score_b, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      x1    x2    x3    x4 score_a score_b score
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    NA     1     0    NA       1       0     1
#> 2     1    NA    NA     1       1       1     2
#> 3     1     0    NA     1       1       1     2
#> 4     0     0     1    NA       0       1     1
#> 5     0    NA     0     0       0       0     0
#> 6    NA     0     1     0       0       1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` to convert NAs into 0 befroe summing them up.

```
na_sum <- \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)
```

Then try two-step score computing:

```
mutate(x,
  score = case_when(
    x1 %in% 0 & x2 %in% 0 ~ 0L,
    x1 %in% 1 | x2 %in% 1 ~ 1L
  ),
  score = case_when(
    x3 %in% 0 & x4 %in% 0 ~ na_sum(score) + 0,
    x3 %in% 1 | x4 %in% 1 ~ na_sum(score) + 1,
    TRUE ~ score + 0
  )
)
```

Computing additional columns would help to clearify all the rules.

```
mutate(x,
  score1 = case_when(
    x1 %in% 0 & x2 %in% 0 ~ 0L,
    x1 %in% 1 | x2 %in% 1 ~ 1L
  ),
  score2 = case_when(
    x3 %in% 0 & x4 %in% 0 ~ 0,
    x3 %in% 1 | x4 %in% 1 ~ 1,
  ),
  score = na_sum(score1) + na_sum(score2)
)
```